Cannot interact with tags that are overflowing the visible Watched Tags widget on the new frontpage
The "watched tags" box on the top right of the redesigned home page previously showed a couple of tags and at least had half the clickable tag box for the next line.  As of this morning, it's trimmed to just the first five tags alphabetically.
There isn't a direct way to click on a tag I'm interested in, say, one that begins with "k".  The "gear wheel" and "See all" both bring the same editing pop-up, where I can add and remove tags, but there's no way to click on one to go to the list of questions.
It'd be great if this widget could be moved to somewhere there was more vertical space, like the right sidebar, so the list didn't have to be cut off.


The right side bar is where it was previously though... They moved it because they didn't want it there clearly.

Clarification: you can watch many tags. However, you can't click on the tag to see the questions with it, when the tag is hidden behind the "See all". Also, it's not necessarily 5, depends on the length of the tags. I mean, it's still something that needs to be addressed, it should just be clearer what the exact problem is, because it's not a limit on the number of watched tags.

"It'd be great if this widget could be moved to somewhere there was more vertical space, like the right sidebar" Like it was before, and how it appears on the  Questions page, below the incredibly useful custom filters section that has been removed from the home page? It would be nice, if the page was functional, like the rest of the site; I agree.

Related: Updated Homepage Widgets feedback

For myself the vast majority of time (after landing on the home page and seeing a long list of questions I have no interest in) I want to filter on sql-server tag. Which is not shown due to being later in the alphabet than many of my other watched tags. It used to at least be clickable when expanding  that section but now expanding that section assumes I want to  edit the tags not interact with them

I think this is a workflow we've not given enough attention to for this new homepage (it's been quite a challenge to build something for all kinds of users at once). Let me try rectify that. We can at least make the links in the modal clickable

This is a really poor design. Unexpanded, the dialog box lets you select questions with a specific tag. Then, when you click see all the function of the dialog box changes completely to add and remove watched tags. DOWNRIGHT ANNOYING! It's like having a diary that, when you try to move to next week, it decides it's now your calendar. What are you thinking of?

The tags in the modal are now clickable and navigate to the tag page.
Alternatively, you can use the Questions page which shows the Watched Tags in the right sidebar, which are also clickable.

Is it an intentional design decision to only show ~5 watched tags on the main page?  Why?  I'm more concerned that I can't get to late-in-the-alphabet tags with one click than I am that an indirect process doesn't work.

Not exactly, but it's a consequence of a few things. It's intentional that they're at the top to help new users. And it's intentional that all widgets in the same row are the same size. On wider screens, this means Watched Tags is the same size as Rep and Badges. From there it's design trade-offs (I'm not a designer, but imagine: empty space, vertical space, accessibility, pure aesthetics). We had a scroll bar, now we've got this "See all" link, and there are perhaps some other designs we could experiment with too.
